# Setting a stylesheet on a vertical QT/PyQT/PySide tab widget?

Tags: css, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtabwidget

I have a custom tab widget that set the text to be horizontal on a vertical tab, however, when I implement a style sheet to change the tab once it is selected, I get this:[image]

It should be a uniform box, just like the one here but rotated 90 degrees. I believe that I need a way to change it so that height changes width and width changes height as I define the tab in a stylesheet with a height and width however this stylesheet refers to a normal tab widget, not a custom vertical one.

Feel free to offer any advice on my current code, whether it be about the custom tab widget class or my actual class. I am relatively new to QT

This is all of my code:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)
            painter.restore()

class VerticalTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar())
        self.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)

class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.w1 = self
        self.w1.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.w1.setWindowTitle("")
        self.w1.setFixedSize(780, 459)
        palette = self.w1.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.w1.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.w1.setPalette(palette)
        self.w1.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.w1.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1 = VerticalTabWidget(self.w1)
        self.tab1.move(0, 0)
        self.tab1.resize(290, 460)
        self.tab1.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)
        palette = self.tab1.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.tab1.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.tab1.setPalette(palette)
        self.tab1.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.tab1.setToolTip("")
        
        self.ta1 = QWidget(self.tab1)
        self.ta1.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.ta1.setWindowTitle("")
        self.ta1.move(0, 0)
        self.ta1.resize(263, 456)
        palette = self.ta1.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.ta1.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.ta1.setPalette(palette)
        self.ta1.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.ta1.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.addTab(self.ta1, "General")
        self.ta2 = QWidget(self.tab1)
        self.ta2.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.ta2.setWindowTitle("")
        self.ta2.move(0, 0)
        self.ta2.resize(263, 456)
        palette = self.ta2.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.ta2.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.ta2.setPalette(palette)
        self.ta2.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.ta2.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.addTab(self.ta2, "Advanced")
        self.ta3 = QWidget(self.tab1)
        self.ta3.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.ta3.setWindowTitle("")
        self.ta3.move(0, 0)
        self.ta3.resize(263, 446)
        palette = self.ta3.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.ta3.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.ta3.setPalette(palette)
        self.ta3.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.ta3.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.addTab(self.ta3, "Selected State")
        self.ta4 = QWidget(self.tab1)
        self.ta4.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.ta4.setWindowTitle("")
        self.ta4.move(0, 0)
        self.ta4.resize(263, 446)
        palette = self.ta4.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.ta4.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.ta4.setPalette(palette)
        self.ta4.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.ta4.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.addTab(self.ta4, "Hover States")
        self.ta5 = QWidget(self.tab1)
        self.ta5.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.ta5.setWindowTitle("")
        self.ta5.move(0, 0)
        self.ta5.resize(263, 446)
        palette = self.ta5.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.ta5.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.ta5.setPalette(palette)
        self.ta5.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.ta5.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.addTab(self.ta5, "Disabled State")
        self.ta6 = QWidget(self.tab1)
        self.ta6.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.ta6.setWindowTitle("")
        self.ta6.move(0, 0)
        self.ta6.resize(263, 456)
        palette = self.ta6.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.ta6.backgroundRole(), QColor(223, 230, 233, 255))
        self.ta6.setPalette(palette)
        self.ta6.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.ta6.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.addTab(self.ta6, "Advanced States")
        self.group1 = QGroupBox(self.w1)
        self.group1.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.group1.setTitle("")
        self.group1.move(390, 120)
        self.group1.resize(280, 220)
        palette = self.group1.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.group1.backgroundRole(), QColor(238, 238, 238, 255))
        self.group1.setPalette(palette)
        self.group1.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.group1.setToolTip("")
        self.button1 = QToolButton(self.group1)
        self.button1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.button1.setText("Preview Button")
        self.button1.move(80, 90)
        self.button1.resize(120, 40)
        self.button1.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.button1.setToolTip("")
        self.tab1.setStyleSheet("""

QTabBar{
  background-color:#dfe6e9;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
  background-color: #123456;
}

QTabBar::tab {
height: 100px; width: 70px;border: 2px;
}
""")
        return self.w1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Widget1()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating things.

Translating the sizes just makes it all confusing, because the tab painting follows the size provided by the style (which you forced as 70x100, not 100x70).

Also, forcing the size of the tab is problematic, and since you're using the original (vertical) option for drawing, this will potentially clip (or overflow) the tab text, since you transposed the rectangle, so you should remove the `width` and `height` properties from the style sheet.

The solution is to minimize the transposition, and use the style option features to properly draw the contents, specifically setting the `shape` to a horizontal one so that the label is properly drawn.

```py
class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        hint = super().tabSizeHint(index).transposed()
        return QSize(
            max(hint.width(), 100), 
            max(hint.height(), 70)
        )

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QStyleOptionTab()

        current = self.currentIndex()
        for i in range(self.count()):
            if i == current:
                continue
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            opt.shape = QTabBar.RoundedNorth
            painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)

        self.initStyleOption(opt, current)
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
        opt.shape = QTabBar.RoundedNorth
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)
```

Notes:

- the current tab is always painted *above* the others;
- learn to use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead of fixed geometries;
- always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): 99% of the contents of `gui()` is completely useless for the scope of the question;

Comment: Thank you for the code and the explanation. For anyone who gets the error QSize is undefined add QtCore. before it and it will work. I notice that the painter allows for parts of the widget to be moved, could this be used to create a line edit similar to the one google has, which when activated will shift the placeholder text to the top left of the border, could I achieve something similar with the QSytlePainter and draw control.

Comment: @NejoFS painting only allows to paint within the content of the widget, so, as long as what you want to paint is within the widget it is doable. I suggest you to carefully study the documentation of QStyle and QPainter, then if you still are not able to do it, create a new question.

Comment: So the main method of changing widget look and visual aspects is through stylesheets and QStyle with QPainter, is there any other useful ways/methods to change the looks of widgets?

Comment: To keep consistency with the standard widget behavior, yes, you can only use stylesheets (or QPalette for colors, but be careful in not mixing them), QStyle, and obviously QPainter for completely custom painting.